Why doesn't Canvas.SetLeft and .SetTop work in this WPF code?
I have dynamically create images added to a canvas and later need to move them. But this code does not do the job:
   int slotCount = _cardSlots.Count;

   for (int i = 0; i < slotCount; i++)
   {
       Canvas.SetLeft(_cardSlots[i].Card.CardImage.Image, _cardSlots[i].ScreenRectangle.X );
       Canvas.SetTop(_cardSlots[i].Card.CardImage.Image, _cardSlots[i].ScreenRectangle.Y);  
   }

The images don't change position. I tried canvas.invalidatevisual but this made no difference.
However, if I use the same code but not in a loop, the images do move position. e.g.:
  Canvas.SetLeft(_cardSlots[0].Card.CardImage.Image, _cardSlots[0].ScreenRectangle.X);
  Canvas.SetTop(_cardSlots[0].Card.CardImage.Image, _cardSlots[0].ScreenRectangle.Y);
  Canvas.SetLeft(_cardSlots[1].Card.CardImage.Image, _cardSlots[1].ScreenRectangle.X);
  Canvas.SetTop(_cardSlots[1].Card.CardImage.Image, _cardSlots[1].ScreenRectangle.Y);

foreach did not work either. _cardSlots represents a virutal slot where a card will be placed.
A CardSlot has a related Card. Each Card contains a CardImage object, which has the Image as a property. Each CardSlot also has a Rectangle, the latter which has the Left and Right properties for the canvas for that slot.
The indices for the cards change over time and are then reassigned to the slot. So the slots don't change, just the cards that reside in that slot, which needs to then be reflected on the canvas.
So this code works. Does anyone know why please? I appreciate any help.

From what you are showing here it is not possible tell why the code won't work. What exactly is _cardSlots? In general, better use a foreach loop like foreach (var cardSlot in _cardSlots) { ... }

@Clemens foreach did not work either. _cardSlots represents a virutal slot where a card will be placed. A CardSlot has a related Card. Each Card contains a CardImage object, which has the Image as a property. Each CardSlot also has a Rectangle, the latter which has the Left and Right properties for the canvas for that slot. The indices for the cards change over time and are then reassigned to the slot. So the slots don't change, just the cards that reside in that slot, which needs to then be reflected on the canvas.

Please edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code, especially the type and variable declarations.

My guess is that the issue is related to how the canvas are being updated within the loop. Although you didn't provide much context, here's a solution I tested that works by adding a new UpdateCardPositions method, which updates the UI and ensures everything is refreshed correctly. I called the method through a button click, but you can trigger it with any event you prefer.
The InitializeCardSlots method initializes a list of card slots (_cardSlots) with dummy data for testing purposes. It creates several Image elements, sets their size and source, and positions them on the canvas. These images are then added to the canvas and the _cardSlots list, each wrapped in a CardSlot object with a Card and a ScreenRectangle.
The UpdateCardPositions method is designed to update the positions of the cards on the canvas. It iterates over the list of card slots (_cardSlots). For each card slot, it calculates new X and Y positions based on the current index (i). The Dispatcher.Invoke method is used to ensure that the UI updates are performed on the main thread, which in WPF is necessary for thread safety. The positions of the images are then updated on the canvas using Canvas.SetLeft and Canvas.SetTop.
The CanvasButton_Click method is an event handler for the button click event. When the button is clicked, it triggers the UpdateCardPositions method to update the card positions on the canvas.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace Namespace
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private List<CardSlot> _cardSlots;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeCardSlots();
        }

        private void InitializeCardSlots()
        {
            // Initializing _cardSlots with dummy data for testing purposes
            _cardSlots = new List<CardSlot>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var cardImage = new Image
                {
                    Width = 100,
                    Height = 150,
                    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://via.placeholder.com/100x150"))
                };

                Canvas.SetLeft(cardImage, i * 110);
                Canvas.SetTop(cardImage, i * 160);

                canvas.Children.Add(cardImage);

                _cardSlots.Add(new CardSlot
                {
                    Card = new Card { CardImage = new CardImage { Image = cardImage } },
                    ScreenRectangle = new Rect(i + 110, i + 160, 100, 150)
                });
            }
        }

        private async void UpdateCardPositions()
        {
            int slotCount = _cardSlots.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < slotCount; i++)
            {
                var image = _cardSlots[i].Card.CardImage.Image;
                var x = _cardSlots[i].ScreenRectangle.X * i;
                var y = _cardSlots[i].ScreenRectangle.Y - i;
                
                canvas.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(image, x);
                    Canvas.SetTop(image, y);
                });

                // Small delay to resamble an animated affect
                await Task.Delay(50);
            }
        }

        private void CanvasButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateCardPositions();
        }
    }

    public class CardSlot
    {
        public Card Card { get; set; }
        public Rect ScreenRectangle { get; set; }
    }

    public class Card
    {
        public CardImage CardImage { get; set; }
    }

    public class CardImage
    {
        public Image Image { get; set; }
    }
}

Make sure your XAML is set up like this:
<StackPanel>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <Button x:Name="CanvasButton"
            Content="Press me!"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Click="CanvasButton_Click" />
</StackPanel>


"it is possible that the properties are being updated but the canvas isn't being notified to refresh the UI elements" - that is not true. Setting Canvas.Left or Top will always update the UI.

@Clemens you're right, I'm sorry. I was thinking of a threading problem but that would give a threading exception instead of not updating the elements. I will edit out the incorrect information.
